# I have a list with check box, i want to call view modal's Selected Property only when check box is checked

Tags: wpf, vb.net

```
<dg:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="2" 
                                     BorderThickness="1"
                                     BorderBrush="{DynamicResource stdTextboxBroderBrush}"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjList, Mode=OneWay}"                                      
                                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                     Height="200"
                                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                         
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"                                     
                                     acb:PreviewKeydownEventArgsHandler.HandlePreViewKeyDown="True"
                                     SelectionUnit="FullRow">
                                <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
```

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectFlag, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                                </CheckBox>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This is my WPF List .. i want to rise my Selected property only when my checkbox is checked and i want to do it only with MVVM style.

Comment: Did I understand correctly, you want to realize behavior if item is unchecked it can not be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly it's easy

`<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Model.IsSelected}"/>`

And your model should realise INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I m using On Property Changed for every property which is used in WPF UI. Should I Implement INotifyPropertyChanged then do subscribe it for any change in list?

Comment: You should use ObservableCollection, List isn't suitable for using as ItemsSource.

Comment: yes, it works by using ObservableCollection . and the second way I have tried is I used the Checked event of checkbox and bind it to view model both work fine.